# How can I fail a .NET build if a project references a NuGet package with known vulnerabilities

Tags: .net, security, nuget, devops, nuget-package

I can find most vulnerable packages using `dotnet list package --vulnerable` but to put that in a build step and fail the build would require some text parsing. Is there some easier way, such as a webservice that returns the same information in JSON where it would be easier to determine whether the returned data indicates a vulnerability?

Answer (score 0):

There's no current right way to do this. See this feature request: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/16852

As suggested on the issue, one workaround is to look for `has the following vulnerable packages` in the output.